# Timeout Expired error

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

There is a Web Page in my Project in which RadGrid is there which displays multiple records in it. Sometimes the web page works fine but sometimes it shows below error-

[image]

In above snapshot, `[Invoice].[ups_tbl_Request_Query_Select_AdminView]` is the name of Stored Procedure.
**Edit** 
 Stored Procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [Invoice].[usp_tbl_Request_Query_Select_AdminView]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here

    @Status tinyint = Null,
    @SearchValue nvarchar(50) = Null

AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here

    If (LTRIM(@SearchValue) = '')
        Set @SearchValue = Null

    Select Distinct
        R.RequestID,
        R.RequisitionNo,
        R.BarcodeNo,
        R.IsThreeWayMatch,
        R.IsUrgent,
        R.CreatedBy,
        R.TotalAmount,
        R.TotalInvoiceAmount,
        R.CompanyCode as BuyerNo,
        W.Action,
        W.CreatedDate,
        --R.CreatedDate,
        R.SubmissionDate,
        CASE
        WHEN (R.IsThreeWayMatch in (1))
            THEN X.BuyerName   
        ELSE R.Company   
         END AS BuyerName,

        X.SupplierNo,
        X.SupplierName,
        X.InvoiceNo,
        S.RequestStatus,    
        --w.UserName,
        --(select top 1 w.CreatedDate from Invoice.tbl_WorkflowHistory W where w.CreatedBy = R.CreatedBy and R.RequestID = W.RequestID order by w.CreatedDate desc) as date1,
        (select top 1 w.UserName from Invoice.tbl_WorkflowHistory (NOLOCK) W where w.CreatedBy = R.CreatedBy and R.RequestID = W.RequestID order by w.CreatedDate desc) as UserName

    INTO #Records1

    From Invoice.tbl_Request (NOLOCK) R
        Left Join Invoice.tbl_Xml(NOLOCK) X On X.XmlID = R.XmlID
        Left Join Invoice.tbl_WorkflowHistory (NOLOCK) W On W.RequestID = R.RequestID
        Left Join Invoice.tbl_RequestStatus (NOLOCK) S On S.RequestStatusNo = R.[Status]
    Where ((IsNull(R.RequisitionNo, '') Like '%' + Coalesce(@SearchValue, R.RequisitionNo, '') + '%')
            Or (IsNull(R.BarcodeNo, '') Like '%' + Coalesce(@SearchValue, R.BarcodeNo, '') + '%')
            --Or (IsNull(X.BuyerNo, '') Like '%' + Coalesce(@SearchValue, X.BuyerNo, '') + '%')
            --Or (IsNull(X.SupplierNo, '') Like '%' + Coalesce(@SearchValue, X.SupplierNo, '') + '%')
            Or (IsNull(R.Company, '') Like '%' + Coalesce(@SearchValue, R.Company, '') + '%')
            Or (IsNull(X.SupplierName, '') Like '%' + Coalesce(@SearchValue, X.SupplierName, '') + '%'))
        --And (W.[Role] = 'AP Admin'
        --  Or W.[Role] = 'AP Associate')
        And R.[Status] = IsNull(@Status ,R.[Status]) 
    Order By R.RequisitionNo


    SELECT * FROM 
    (
    SELECT * FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY RequisitionNo ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC) RowNumber FROM #Records1 ) AS t
    WHERE RowNumber = 1

    ) AS a Order By RequisitionNo

END
```

HTML code:

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsDocumentHistoryAdmin" runat="server" SelectMethod="Query_Test" TypeName="atQuest.Projects.Sunway.IPRRequest" SortParameterName="orderBy">
                        <SelectParameters>
                            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlStatus" Name="status" PropertyName="SelectedValue"
                                Type="Int32" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true"  />
                            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtSearch" Name="searchValue" PropertyName="Text"
                                Type="String" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" />
                        </SelectParameters>
                    </asp:ObjectDataSource>
                    <telerik:RadGrid ID="qgDocumentHistoryAdmin" runat="server" DataSourceID="odsDocumentHistoryAdmin"
                                AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AllowFilteringByColumn="True" ShowGroupPanel="True"
                                CellSpacing="0" GridLines="None" Width="100%" Skin="Outlook">
                                <ClientSettings AllowDragToGroup="True" />
                                <GroupingSettings CaseSensitive="false"></GroupingSettings>
                                <MasterTableView AllowFilteringByColumn="true" AllowMultiColumnSorting="false" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                                    CommandItemDisplay="Top" DataKeyNames="RequisitionNo" EnableGroupsExpandAll="true"
                                    GroupLoadMode="Client" PageSize="50">
                                    <CommandItemSettings ShowAddNewRecordButton="false" ShowExportToExcelButton="true" />
                                    <SortExpressions>
                                        <telerik:GridSortExpression FieldName="RequisitionNo" SortOrder="Descending" />
                                    </SortExpressions>
                                    <PagerStyle AlwaysVisible="True" PageSizeControlType="RadComboBox" Position="Bottom" PageSizes="50,100,150,200" />
                                    <Columns>
                                        //all GridBound columnc
                                    </Columns>
                                </MasterTableView>
                                <ExportSettings SuppressColumnDataFormatStrings="True" IgnorePaging="True" ExportOnlyData="True" Excel-Format="ExcelML" OpenInNewWindow="True" FileName="eAPDocHistory" Excel-FileExtension="xls">
                                </ExportSettings>
                            </telerik:RadGrid>
```

Class file code:

```
[DataObjectMethod(DataObjectMethodType.Select, true)]
        public static IPRRequests Query_Test(int? status, string searchValue, string orderBy)
        {
            IPRRequests iPRRequests = new IPRRequests();
            Data data = new Data();
            Dictionary<string, object> input = new Dictionary<string, object>()
            {
                {"@Status", status},
                {"@SearchValue", searchValue}
            };
            DataTable dt = data.ExecuteQuery(CommandType.StoredProcedure, "[Invoice].[usp_tbl_Request_Query_Select_AdminView]", input);
            if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                DataView dv = dt.DefaultView;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(orderBy))
                {
                    string colName = orderBy.Replace(" DESC", "");
                    try
                    {
                        //dv.Sort = orderBy.Replace(colName, FieldMapping[colName.Trim()]);
                        dv.Sort = orderBy;
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        throw new Exception("orderby:" + orderBy + ";colname:" + colName);
                    }

                    dt = dv.ToTable();
                }

                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    iPRRequests.Add(new IPRRequest(dr, true));
                }
                dt.Dispose();
                dv.Dispose();
            }

            return iPRRequests;
        }
```

I am unable to understand the reason of this error which occurs most of the time but not always. 
 Please let me know the reason of this issue and how can I resolve it in a simple way. 
 Please reply.

Comment: run the sql profiler and see what causing delay?

Comment: Are you using a SQLCommand Object?

Comment: Please include the stored procedure that you are running (not the name, the actual code).

Comment: Check my answer and tell me if something is not clear.

Comment: @thewisegod: Thank you for the reply. I am not using SQLCommand Object. I am binding the RadGrid using `ObjectDataSource` which has `SelectMethod="Query_Test"` from a class file. Please check the **Edit** section in my posted question.

Comment: @RonBeyer: Thank you for the reply. Please check the **Edit** section in my posted question. I had added all the code in it. Please let me know how to resolve it.

Comment: When you run that stored procedure in SQL Management Studio, how long does it take to run?

Comment: @RonBeyer: Thank you for the reply. It loads/shows initial data in 36 seconds.
And loads all the data, returned by the query, in 1 min & 10 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look at your query to see why it's taking so long.  Sometimes your query is running longer than the default command timeout of 30 seconds.

The [SqlCommand.CommandTimeout Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout(v=vs.110).aspx) have a default command timeout of 30 seconds.  You can try to increase it to 60 seconds.

The following code was taken from MSDN site.

```
 using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
 {
     connection.Open();
     SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
     // Setting command timeout to 60 second
     command.CommandTimeout = 60;
     try {
         command.ExecuteNonQuery();
     }
     catch (SqlException e) {
         Console.WriteLine("Got expected SqlException due to command timeout ");
         Console.WriteLine(e);
     }
}
```

Comment: If its taking 15+ seconds to return a query, increasing it to 30 seconds is the wrong fix.

Comment: Yes, but the OP is asking why he is getting this error.  By explain the error and what is causing it will eventually leads him to improve his query. Hopefully his next question on SO would be along the lines of how do I improve my query.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Please let me know the best way to fix this problem ? Please re-view the **Edit** section in my posted question again and let me know what shall I change in my query ?

Comment: @BlackFrog: Thank you so much. Your solution worked.

Answer (score 1):

The view which you are loading have a lot of records and this leads to timeout, because there is not enough time for loading. The easiest solution for this is to increase the timeouts. But I don't advise this approach.

The smart way to do it is to load only the records which are visible. I'm giving you an example. When the page is open, you see for an example only 20 records. So your query should load only 20 records. You can check [SQL RowNumber](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx). In this article you are interest in **Returning a subset of rows**.

**Here is an example**

```
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() 
        OVER (ORDER BY EmployeeName) AS Row, 
        EmployeeId, EmployeeName, Salary 
    FROM Employees) AS EMP
WHERE Row BETWEEN 20 AND 40
```

This is an easy example how to show only specific records. So if you have 20 records per page and you are on page 2, you will have query like this.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Please let me know what do you mean by `load only the records which are visible`. Since I display records in RadGrid, from a Database table using Select query(Left Join in 3 tables). So whatever records are there in table I have to show all of them. In RadGrid, each page has 50 records to display. Please re-view the **Edit** section in my posted question again and let me know what shall I change in my query ?

Comment: @user3196511 lets say for an example you have 100 k records in the database for this table. When you open the page you see only 10,20 or more depending how much you see per page. So you don't need to load 10k, you need to load the number of visible records on the page. So instead 10k you will load 20 for an example.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I got your logic. If l do the suggested change in Stored Procedure, will it affect the RadGrid's records page wise (necessary to show 50 records per page in RadGrid) ? i.e., 1st 50 records in 1st page then next 50 records in next page and so on ? Please let me know where to make suggested change in above defined Stored Procedure ?

Comment: @user3196511 Like I see I'm giving you an example how to do it. I'm not going to write your code with 100 line query, also you can into changing all the OR to UNIONS this will give performance boost. For my answer to be done you need to do a lot of work on the query and also in the rad grid. Also try to build your query better because this look like a mess !

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a SqlCommand object set it like this:

```
your command object.CommandTimeout = 0;
```

And see if that solves your problem. If it does you can leave it like that or change the value to something that you feel is large enough.

Answer (score 0):

this is basically database not communication with the webpage. Either there is some connection string problem or it may be your net connection is slow, if your database is online

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Yes the Database is the Live DB, hosted on server. Please re-view the **Edit** section in my posted question again and let me know what shall I change in my query ?

Comment: this error usually occurs when server is not responding. if ur database is working fine sometimes and sometimes show this error, ur code is perfect bt the problem is your severs is not responding . it may be due to slow internet connection or due to server not in active state

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Please let me know if any solution is there for this issue?